# Expression Tree, Multiple string.Contains predicate could not be translated

Tags: c#, expression-trees

I am trying to build a dynamic search that looks for a string in a specific set of properties.
There isn't any problem in doing that for a single property, but when I add more than one it throws the following error:

> InvalidOperationException: The LINQ expression '
> DbSet`<Person>`
> .Where(a => a.Id.ToString().Contains("test") || a.Name.ToString().Contains("test"))
>
> could not be translated.**
> Either rewrite the query in a form that can be translated, or switch to client evaluation explicitly by inserting a call to either AsEnumerable(), AsAsyncEnumerable(), ToList(), or ToListAsync().

```
    public class Person {
     public string Name {get; set;}
     public int Id {get; set;}
    }   

    private static Expression GetMemberExpression(ParameterExpression parameter, string propertyName)
    {
        Expression body = parameter;
        foreach (var member in propertyName.Split('.'))
        {
            body = Expression.PropertyOrField(body, member);
        }
        return body;
    }


    public static IQueryable<T> Search<T>(this IQueryable<T> source, string searchCriteria, string searchQuery)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(searchQuery) || string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(searchCriteria))
        {
            return source;
        }

        ParameterExpression parameter = Expression.Parameter(source.ElementType);
        List<Expression> expTree = new List<Expression>();

        foreach (var propertyName in searchCriteria.Split(","))
        {
            Expression memberExpression = GetMemberExpression(parameter, propertyName);

            MethodCallExpression toStringExpression = Expression.Call(memberExpression, typeof(object).GetMethod("ToString"));

            ConstantExpression constantExpression = Expression.Constant(searchQuery.ToLower(), typeof(string));

            MethodCallExpression containsExpression = Expression.Call(toStringExpression, typeof(string)
                .GetMethod("Contains", new[] { typeof(string) }), constantExpression);

            expTree.Add(containsExpression);
        }

        Expression body = expTree
            .Skip(1)
            .Aggregate(expTree.FirstOrDefault(),
                (current, exp) => Expression.OrElse(current, exp));

        var lambda = Expression.Lambda(body, parameter);

        Expression whereCallExpression = Expression.Call(typeof(Queryable),
            "Where",
            new Type[] { source.ElementType },
            source.Expression, lambda);

        return source.Provider.CreateQuery<T>(whereCallExpression);
    }

public async Task Test() {
  await dbContext.People.Search("Name","test").ToListAsync(); // this is fine
  await dbContext.People.Search("Id,Name","test").ToListAsync(); // Throws an exception

}
```

Comment: You are apparently using EF Core 3.x? EF Core 3.1 can't translate `ToString` on `string`s.

Comment: This is correct. My current version is 3.1.5

Comment: 1. Don't use `typeof(object)` to lookup `ToString` - you know the type, it is `memberExpresion.Type`, use that. 2. Don't add `ToString` when `memberExpression.Type` is `typeof(string)`.

Comment: I removed the ToString Expression for string type and now it works. Thanks.